# Стоит ли использовать Xamarin для мобильной разработки?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Мне интересна тема мобильной разработки, но переходить на Java/Kotlin, Flatter, React Native и прочие Kivy особого желания нет, C# мне больше по душе. В связи с этим я обратил внимание на Xamarin. Знаю, что сейчас Майкрософт уже выпустила ему замену, но там пока очень мало литературы, ещё ничего не понятно, а Xamarin существует давно.

Кто-нибудь разрабатывал под мобилки на этом фреймворке и каково ваше мнение о нём? Стоит ли осваивать (и затем переходить на его замену, которую только что выпустила Майкрософт)? Ведь судя по их статье замена, это по сути следующая ступень развития Xamarin.

Каковы плюсы и минусы Xamarin? Насколько сложные приложения на нём можно создавать, или только Hello World? Или же его вообще нет смысла рассматривать и всё-таки следует посмотреть на Kotlin?

Заранее благодарен за ответы и советы.

Comment: "Стоит ли использовать C# для программирования? А молоток для забивания гвоздей?" Вопрос-фрустрация? Xamarin - мощный инструмент для создания чего угодно, ну разве кроме 3Д игр. MAUI - отличная ему актуальная замена, хоть пока и сыроватая. Решать вам, что брать и как писать.

Comment: По моему, в комментарии выше-фактический ответ. Разработка на ксасарине с одной стороны-такая же привычная, как на wpf-winforms, с другой стороны-там есть инструменты буквально для всего. Это же Майкрософт, монстр, который заранее решил все ваши проблемы! - и сейчас я пишу почти без иронии. А Котлин - просто хайповый. Ну, типа, на вечеринке похвастаться перед девочками своего двора "А я вот пишу на котлине!"

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но меня смущают нелестные отзывы о Xamarin от разработчиков на различных форумах, в соцсетях, на том же ютубе. Пишут, что якобы мобильные приложения созданные на нём очень много весят, сильно потребляют память и тормозят. Не раз натыкался на высказывания, что такие приложения уступают в плане производительности приложениям созданным на Flatter и React Native и что ничего серьёзного на Xamarin для мобилок создать нельзя. Ставят в один ряд этот фреймворк даже с Kivy. Что это, обычный хейт со стороны недоброжелателей Xamarin, или есть доля правды?